# How to capture App Crash details in custom Framework to improve framework functionality?

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, frameworks

We created a custom iOS framework/sdk and sharing with the clients to integrate in their iOS application. We don't integrated 3rd party frameworks to track SDK/App crash and analytics due to some policies. So, we decided to capture SDK/Framework crash and send to our server to improve our Framework.

As we gone through some blogs, we have to add "NSException" to capture Crash logs. I created a utility class in our SDK to handle the exceptions like below,

```
import Foundation

@objc public class CCrashlytics: NSObject {

    @objc static let shared = CCrashlytics()
    
    @objc public override init() {
        // Initialization code, if any
        super.init()
    }
    
    // Method to simulate a crash
    @objc public func crashTheSDK() {
        let array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        let _ = array[10]
    }
    
    // Method to handle exceptions
    @objc public func handleException(exception: NSException) {
        // Collect crash information
        let stackTrace = exception.callStackSymbols.joined(separator: "\n")
        let exceptionName = exception.name.rawValue
        let exceptionReason = exception.reason ?? "No reason provided"
        
        // Log crash information locally or send it to a remote server
        print("\n Exception: \(exceptionName), Reason: \(exceptionReason)\nStackTrace:\n\(stackTrace)")                        
    }
}
```

And added the below code in my sample/demo client app (Obj-C app) after our SDK initialisation,

```
CCrashlytics *crashlytics = [[CCrashlytics alloc] init];
            [crashlytics crashTheSDK];
            NSException *expection = [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Custom Expection" reason:@"Simulate Exception" userInfo:nil];
            [crashlytics handleExceptionWithException:expection];
```

But, when we try to crash the SDK, app stops and the Exception is not executed. Could you please help me to do this? Thanks in advance.

I also tried to capture the Exception in the app itself from "

> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

". It is working and am able to get the app crash details. But, don't know how to do the same in the standalone custom Framework/SDK. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Currently your app crash on `[crashlytics crashTheSDK];`, so `NSException *expection... handleExceptionWithException...` isn't called.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you need to call `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler()` at start of the app (to be able to catch the exceptions)

Comment: Thank you. I have added the NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler in the SDK Utility class and call this Class function from Client App's AppDelegate, DidFinish delegate. App crashed but, never the NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler called in the SDK.

@objc public class func registerException() {
    
        NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in
            print("\n Exception in SDK \n")
        }
    }